# Cross domain issue with IFrame in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

We intend to access another app url which is hosted on the same machine, but on different port. So my Angular 2 application `http://localhost:8081/app/` is trying to open a site hosted on same server but different port i.e. `localhost:9100`

```
We are trying to access following url in an iframe
url = http://localhost:9100/custom/getCustomPage

<iframe id="customFrame" *ngIf="url !== null" frameborder="0" [src]="url"></iframe>
```

> Error on Chrome/Firefox DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:9100" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at http://localhost:9100/custom/getCustomPage Where Host:localhost:9100 Referer:http://localhost:8081/app/

I have added below headers to Response Filter:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-length, Allow
```

Please help me identify a workaround so that iFrame allows to display the results.

This is currently working fine in IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return your URL as a trusted url using Dom sanitizer to bypass security. Here is what you can do:

**In your html:**

```
<iframe [src]='getSourceURL()'></iframe>
```

**... and in your typescript:**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    ....
})
export class YourComponent {      

    yourIFrameUrl: string;
    constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    getSourceURL() {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.yourIFrameUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Faisal, I have used DOMSanitizer to bypass security.
However the Error occurs in response page wherever it is trying to make reference to 
window.parent
locale: window.parent.dojo? window.parent.dojo.locale : 'en'

Comment: I could not make it work using `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` but `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` did the job.