# DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9000" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I wanna get a screenshot of iframe, I use Angular 9.

[image]

component.html:

```
 <div>
   <img id='img' />
 </div>

<div>
     <iframe id="iframe" *ngIf="fileUrl" [src]="getFileUrl()"></iframe>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
// take screenshot
var body = $('iframe').contents().find('body')[0];
      html2canvas(body).then((canvas: any) => {
        var base64encodedstring = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
        $('#img').attr('src', base64encodedstring);
      });
```

Comment: What does this **getFileUrl()** function do?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508270/cross-domain-issue-with-iframe-in-angular2

Comment: No problem with display iframe content, the problem is can not get a screenshot from the iframe.

Comment: getFileUrl(): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.fileUrl);
  }
 @Muthupriya

Comment: Could you please confirm me that if you directly provided your this.fileUrl in html file, is that image is shown or not? @ahmed hassan

Comment: No, not shown, it needs to get from method @Muthupriya

Comment: Do you have control over the thing that is loaded in the iframe..? It seems to at least be loaded from a different domain..